# Handle programmaticaly created spinners and locate them to bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-alertdialog

I am developing app, where you can fill your school shedule(with auth etc.)
In dialog class I create new Spinner + TextView. How to allocate them in MainActivity and how to set content view to the bottom of the list? I know there's some LayoutParams thing, but I can't understand it.

Also it would be great if you can help me to remove items from Dialog window after choosing.

Code:

```
public class OtherSubjectsDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().setTitle("Title!");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
    v.findViewById(R.id.btn_inf).setOnClickListener(this);
    v.findViewById(R.id.btn_phys).setOnClickListener(this);
    v.findViewById(R.id.btn_soc).setOnClickListener(this);
    v.findViewById(R.id.btn_chem).setOnClickListener(this);
    v.findViewById(R.id.btn_biol).setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void onClick(View v) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.alignWithParent = true;
    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(super.getContext());
    ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = null;
    TextView textView = new TextView(super.getContext());
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_inf:
            adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(super.getContext(), R.array.inf_groups_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            textView.setText("Группа по информатике:");
            break;
        case R.id.btn_phys:
            adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(super.getContext(), R.array.phys_groups_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            textView.setText("Группа по физике:");
            break;
        case R.id.btn_soc:
            adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(super.getContext(), R.array.soc_groups_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            textView.setText("Группа по обществознанию:");
            break;
        case R.id.btn_chem:
            adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(super.getContext(), R.array.chem_groups_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            textView.setText("Группа по химии:");
            break;
        case R.id.btn_biol:
            adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(super.getContext(), R.array.biol_groups_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            textView.setText("Группа по биологии:");
            break;
    }
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    super.getActivity().addContentView(textView, lp);
    super.getActivity().addContentView(spinner, lp);
    dismiss();
}

public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
}

public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onCancel(dialog);
}
```

}

Dialog fragment xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="Выберите дополнительный предмет:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
    </TextView>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/inf"
            android:id="@+id/btn_inf" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/phys"
            android:id="@+id/btn_phys" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/soc"
            android:id="@+id/btn_soc" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/chem"
            android:id="@+id/btn_chem" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/biol"
            android:id="@+id/btn_biol" />
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you use any xml for containers etc? I find it very useful to inflate a control off of a xml file. Then moderate after this. Show us the fragment XML and Activity XML

Comment: added this. Not sure if it helps

Comment: What is happening with added content? Keep adding textview and spinner every time?

Comment: yes, and moreover I need to find this objects in MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

try this for spinner position:

```
super.getActivity().addContentView(textView, lp);

lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
super.getActivity().addContentView(spinner, lp);
```

Comment: no, after clicking button textview and spinner colliding each other.